# First missing Integer approach's time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time

I want to understand the time complexity of my below algorithm, which is an acceptable answer for the famous first missing integer problem:

```
public int firstMissingPositive(int[] A) {
        int l = A.length;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < l) {
            int j = A[i];
            while (j > 0 && j <= l) {
                int k = A[j - 1];
                A[j - 1] = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                j = k;
            }
            i++;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            if (A[i] != Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                break;
        }
        return i + 1;
    }
```

Observations and findings: 
Looking at the loop structure I thought that the complexity should be more than n as I may visit every element more than twice in some cases. But to my surprise, the solution got accepted. I am not able to understand the complexity.

Comment: So what have **YOU** tried / found out so far? Share **YOUR** findings.

Comment: I have done the same. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking at the nested loops and thinking O(N<sup>2</sup>), but it's not that simple.

Every iteration of the inner loop changes an item in `A` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and there are only N items, so there cannot be more than N iterations of the inner loop *in total*.

The total time is therefore O(N).